# How to make fully responsive mobile apps using react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am still learning react-native. Is there a way to make UI's fully responsive on various sizes and angles of mobile phones?

I am currently designing an app and I am getting few non-responsive issues even if I use **Flexbox**. Whats is the most efficient way top make this app fully responsive on any mobile?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Flexbox without hard Coded values for width and height will make your app responsive on devices plus taking care of diminsions through react-native apis

Answer (score 2):

Things that helped me get started with react native.The more u read the more u learn.
  1) Keeping things neat with [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html)
  2) Never define width and height as constant values.
  3) Use Metrics to get the screen dimensions and use them properly.
  3) Make use of Animated API, React Redux
  4) Refer apps like [f8](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app),[HackerNews](https://github.com/iSimar/HackerNews-React-Native)